# How to Infer such "indirect" assertion with OWL or SWRL?

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

**Knowledge**

lawn is wet today if it rained last night

**Fact**

we found lawn was wet this morning

**Infer**

it rained last night

is this belong to SWRL?

what should i read or check to easily understand these ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, i paste a turtle syntax file.

To do this we have to make some `Object (Predict) Properties`.

```
hasFact
previousDay
nextDay (inverseOf previousDay)
```

Then add some `Individuals` like :

URIs:
wet, rain, today, yesterday

assert today previousDay yesterday and today hasFact wet, next go to swrl tab add this rule.

```
hasFact(?today, wet) ^ previousDay(?today, ?yesterday) -> hasFact(?yesterday, rain)
```

Start REASONING it will work.

[image]

```html
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Annotation properties
#################################################################

###  http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled
<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled> rdf:type owl:AnnotationProperty .


#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#hasFact
:hasFact rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#nextDay
:nextDay rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
         owl:inverseOf :previousDay .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#previousDay
:previousDay rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Data properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#hasValue
:hasValue rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
          rdfs:range [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                       owl:oneOf [ rdf:type rdf:List ;
                                   rdf:first "rain" ;
                                   rdf:rest [ rdf:type rdf:List ;
                                              rdf:first "wet" ;
                                              rdf:rest rdf:nil
                                            ]
                                 ]
                     ] .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#Day
:Day rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#ItRainsLastNight
:ItRainsLastNight rdf:type owl:Class ;
                  owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                        owl:onProperty :previousDay ;
                                        owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                             owl:onProperty :hasFact ;
                                                             owl:hasValue :rain
                                                           ]
                                      ] ;
                  rdfs:subClassOf :Phenomenon .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#Phenomenon
:Phenomenon rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#Today
:Today rdf:type owl:Class ;
       rdfs:subClassOf :Day .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#Weather
:Weather rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#Yesterday
:Yesterday rdf:type owl:Class ;
           rdfs:subClassOf :Day .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#rain
:rain rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               :Weather ;
      :hasValue "rain"^^xsd:string .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#today2018614
:today2018614 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                       :Today ;
              :hasFact :wet ;
              :previousDay :yesterday2018613 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#wet
:wet rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
              :Phenomenon ;
     :hasValue "wet"^^xsd:string .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/monsterstep/ontologies/2018/5/untitled-ontology-31#yesterday2018613
:yesterday2018613 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                           :Yesterday .


#################################################################
#    Rules
#################################################################

<today> rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#Variable> .

<yesterday> rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#Variable> .

[ <http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled> "true"^^xsd:boolean ;
   rdfs:comment ""^^xsd:string ;
   rdfs:label "ItRainsLastNight"^^xsd:string ;
   rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#Imp> ;
   <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#body> [ rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList> ;
                                           rdf:first [ rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#IndividualPropertyAtom> ;
                                                       <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#propertyPredicate> :hasFact ;
                                                       <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#argument1> <today> ;
                                                       <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#argument2> :wet
                                                     ] ;
                                           rdf:rest [ rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList> ;
                                                      rdf:first [ rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#IndividualPropertyAtom> ;
                                                                  <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#propertyPredicate> :previousDay ;
                                                                  <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#argument1> <today> ;
                                                                  <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#argument2> <yesterday>
                                                                ] ;
                                                      rdf:rest rdf:nil
                                                    ]
                                         ] ;
   <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#head> [ rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#AtomList> ;
                                           rdf:first [ rdf:type <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#IndividualPropertyAtom> ;
                                                       <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#propertyPredicate> :hasFact ;
                                                       <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#argument1> <yesterday> ;
                                                       <http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#argument2> :rain
                                                     ] ;
                                           rdf:rest rdf:nil
                                         ]
 ] .

###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.2.8.20170104-2310) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```